# get features out of sentence using C#

Tags: c#, twitter

I am using C# and I got tweets from twitter.
Now the next I want to do is to extract features from that tweets features like:

1. Features A (statistical features): the number of words in a tweet message, and the position of the query word within a tweet.
2. Features B (keyword features): the words in a tweet.
3. Features C (word context features): the words before and after the query word.

for example: Feature A: 7 words in tweet, query word is fifth Feature B: I,am,in,Japan,right,now Feature C: Japan,right

Please suggest me some good method to extract those features. As I am not getting a right way to extract features

Comment: please provide some code as a start, or you question will be probably removed very fast....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of these are very basic string operations that wouldn't really require much specifically from Twitter, assuming you would receive a string from them.

> 1. Features A (statistical features): the number of words in a tweet message and position of a word in a tweet

You could just use the [`String.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method to separate each of your words by a space and then count the number of available elements in the result :

```
// This will return the number of words in your tweet
var wordCount = tweet.Split(' ').Length;

// If you wanted the position of a word, you could just use the IndexOf() method
var queryWordPosition = tweet.Split(' ').IndexOf(query);
```

> 2. Features B (keyword features): the words in a tweet.

Again, the `String.Split()` method comes into play and will store each of your individual words within an array :

```
// This will store each of your words in an array
var words = tweet.Split(' ');
```

> 3. Features C (word context features): the words before and after the query word.

You could again use the previous approach to store each of the values in an array via `String.Split()` and use the [`IndexOf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) method to find your specific query word and then check the previous and next elements of the array:

```
public string[] GetContext(string tweet, string query)
{
      if(tweet == null || !tweet.Contains(query))
      {
          // Your word was not found (or your tweet was null)
          return new string[] {};
      }

      var words = tweet.Split(' ');
      // Find the location of the word
      var queryIndex = words.IndexOf(query);

      // Return the left and right values accordingly
      return new string[]{ queryIndex > 0 ? words[queryIndex - 1] : null, queryIndex < words.Length ? words[queryIndex + 1] : null };
}
```